# Blazor foreach does not render elements after OnInitializedAsync call

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a service that returns a List of Projects to my frontend. The service method is implemented as an async/await method. When I call my service from my frontend thourgh my `OnInitializedAsync()` method I can see that the List is being populated. Then when the time comes to render the page the List of Projects is empty and my component is not rendered. Why is this?

```cs
@using ProjCore.Services.Interfaces

@inject IProjectService ProjectService

<div>
    @foreach (var pro in Projects)
    {
        <h2>Sanitycheck header...</h2>
        <ProjectContainer Project="pro" />
    }
</div>

@code {
    private List<ProjectModel> Projects = new List<ProjectModel>();

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var Projects = await ProjectService.GetProjects();
    }
}
```

In my mind the above should work.

Comment: I seen your code, seemly nothing is wrong. Let's delete folder `bin`, `obj`  then press F5, use Method `Count()` to show only an int number. Then tell me the result. Is List has any items?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, this should not be private:

```
private List<ProjectModel> Projects = new List<ProjectModel>();
```

Set it to be public or protected.  Secondly, you are setting the results from your GetProjects to a local variable and not to the Property that the html is reading from.  Maybe try something like:

```
Projects = await ProjectService.GetProjects();
```

or this flavor if GetProjects doesn't return a List;

```
Projects = await ProjectService.GetProjects().ToList();
```

Mainly, get rid of the "var".  You shouldn't need a StateHasChanged().

Jim

Comment: I see my `var` mistake thank you :) What is the reasoning behind making the `List<ProjectModel>` protected or public? Not contesting your logic, but I am confused to what difference or thinking there's behind this

Comment: Right about the `var` but the Projects member can very well be `private`.

Comment: Perfectly fine to keep Projects List private - otherwise correct answer.

Comment: I might be wrong about the "private" part.  You don't need StateHasChanged, because it is going to redraw after the OnInitializedAsync anyway.  On my Blazor apps, I find I am trying to keep it from redrawing so many times.

Comment: The documentation uses private properties  in the same context

Answer (score 0):

You need to call **StateHasChanged** method so it knows to redraw the UI

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    Projects = await ProjectService.GetProjects();
    await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
}
```

Edit: Yup didn't notice the **var** - you need to not have that, or your creating a local variable

Note about StateHasChanged - You don't need it on event handlers, as it is called automatically at the end of them, although I **think** you do need it on the lifecycle methods like OnInitialized, could be wrong though

Comment: I will try and see which of your answers are most fruitful :) It would make some sense for the window to redraw after the statechange

Comment: You don't need StateHasChanged() in OnIinitialized (unless you need intermediate screen updates). And you certainly don't need InvokeAsync() here.