# Blazor ServerApp. Windows Authentication in Class?

Tags: c#, blazor

I'm using the latest VS2019Pro with Core 3.1.

It seems like Blazor ServerApp has real-time code running within the @code{} tags in the .razor pages. So instead of using APIs to provide the data, I was thinking it would make a lot of sense to just create classes and methods to return the data.

The only issue I am facing is being able to use User.Identity.Name in a Class. Usually this is provided in the .razor pages and in Controllers without issue, but how can I (if it's even possible) use the same User.Identity.Name property within classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the standard .net core auth: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Basically you define a:

```
[CascadingParameter] private Task<AuthenticationState> authenticationStateTask { get; set; }
```

Then you can await it:

```
private async Task LogUsername()
    {
        var authState = await authenticationStateTask;
        var user = authState.User;

        if (user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            _authMessage = $"{user.Identity.Name} is authenticated.";
        }
        else
        {
            _authMessage = "The user is NOT authenticated.";
        }
    }
```

Edit -----

Something like this??

Base Component:

```
[CascadingParameter] private Task<AuthenticationState> authenticationStateTask { get; set; }

public String Username {get;set;}

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync(){
    Username = (await authenticationStateTask).User.Identity.Name;
}
```

Then in your other components:

```
@inherits BaseCompomnent

@Username
```

Comment: Hey Milney, I am getting a no object set to reference error on authState variable. All this code is in a class right?

Comment: @Izacch - Sorry I missed a bit, you need to also decorate the task with [CascadingParameter] attribute. This is because it is passed down by the higher level component. See edited code now

Comment: Hey, I'm still getting that same exception. Am I incorrectly thinking I can use the above code example in a .cs file? I am calling the method from a razor page

Comment: Ah - no you need to have the task in your Blazor file - you would then pass the username through to the other .cs file when you call it. This is how you should be doing it *anyway* though, so you can easily unit-test your other component

Comment: You want your authentication code confined to the bit that does authentication (blazor in this case) and pass it through to the other code, so the other code is re-usable and testable.

Comment: Hey Milney, no problem as long as that is the correct way to do it :) Is there any way to make this code more global to all razor pages so it does not need to be duplicated?

Comment: @enet Why do you think I downvoted? Regardless - you merely said 'using Web Api is most often preferable, as services can be very limiting', which seems like a sweeping generatlization as you didn't explain why it would be prefereable and in which manner it would be limiting... I don't think you added anything material ontop of my answer... And OP marked mine as accepted, so obviously did find it helpful

Comment: I don't think. I know. And it is your right to do so. But the excuse you're offering is nonsensical, especially when it comes from one who suggests to call the StateHasChanged method  from OnInitializedAsync (https://stackoverflow.com/a/63904788/6152891). I've seen your answer then, but did not even bother to down-vote you...

Comment: @enet What? That's completely irrelevant to this discussion... You still never explained why 'using Web Api is most often preferable' or how 'services can be very limiting', therefore your answer is not really saying anything. I never pretended to be an expert at Blazor, its a new tech afterall, but that doesn't change the fact your answer was just two unexplained points, so didn't add anything to mine

Comment: Hey Milney, thanks for your help, I managed to get it to work and can pass up the ClaimsPrincipal instance to class methods for authentication when returning data. Question is, how can I make this code more usable throughout the project without duplicating it? I tried to create a method within a razor components to return ClaimsPrincipal for use in a razor page, but that has the same error when trying to implement it into a class :)

Comment: You can define a BaseComponent with the AuthenticationState task in it, which populates a Username property, then in your other components inherit from that - then you could just use Username directly, if thats what you mean?

Comment: I think that sounds about right yes. I've been toying around trying to get something like that to work for a while, but always get a no object reference exception on the authenticationStateTask local variable within the async method

Comment: @Izacch Update your question with what you tried? Look at my edit - something like that?

Comment: Dude you're a legend, that worked perfect! If I could give you 2x answer I would. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
 IMyRoleManager _myRoleManager;
    private AuthenticationStateProvider _authenticationStateProvider;
    public MyRepository(IMyRoleManager myRoleManager, AuthenticationStateProvider authentication)
    {
        _myRoleManager = myRoleManager;
        _authenticationStateProvider = authentication;
    }

 public async Task<bool> AddRoleToUser(string role)
    {
        var id = await GetUserIdFromAuthenticationStateProviderAsync();
        var result = await _myRoleManager.SetRoleForUser(role, id);
        return result;
    }
```

And in the startup file the correct entries have to be there for services.xxx (identity services)